# Does the Chart.js tooltip not work with logarithmic or the Cartesian Time axis?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, luxon

with my current configs, I can't get tooltips to appear. I am using the latest version of Chart.js, with the latest luxon, and the luxon-chartjs plugin via cdn.

i am using a logarithmic Y axis and cartesian timeline x-axis

i can only get a tooltip to appear when I include a blank callback for label. However, that tooltip that appears only has the unformatted date of the datapoint and no other info. when i ask the label callback to return something, nothing is displayed... when i include a blank callback for title or return anything in the title callback, this works and is displayed. i have hacked together a tooltip but in previous versions I've had no issue with the chart automagically creating these for me.

here is my current code and the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaredgibb/f6cpL5mz/941/)

```
let maxArray, correctArray, incorrectArray, objectArray
let yourImage = new Image()
yourImage.src = `https://res.cloudinary.com/behaviorreportcard/image/upload/w_10,h_18,c_scale/v1623785517/Untitled_10_qbwmx4.png`;
let ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
Chart.defaults.font.size = '10px';
Chart.defaults.plugins.tooltip.enabled = true
const Interval = luxon.Interval,
  DateTime = luxon.DateTime,
  Duration = luxon.Duration;
let minTime = "2017-01-19",
  maxTime = "2017-04-01",
  start = DateTime.fromISO(minTime),
  end = DateTime.fromISO(maxTime),
  duration = Duration.fromObject({
    days: 1
  });
function getStart() {
  let newStart
  if (start.weekday != 7) {
    return start.minus({
      days: start.weekday
    }).toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  } else {
    return start.toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
  }
}
let emptyArray = Interval.fromDateTimes(start, end).splitBy(duration).map(t => ({
  date: t.s.toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
  correct: null,
  incorrect: null
}));
let incomingData = [{
    date: '2017-01-01',
    correct: 10,
    incorrect: 20
  },
  {
    date: '2017-01-02',
    correct: 10,
    incorrect: 0.09
  },
  {
    date: '2017-01-03',
    correct: 0.9,
    incorrect: null
  }, {
    date: '2017-01-04',
    correct: 3,
    incorrect: 0.09
  }, {
    date: '2017-01-27',
    correct: 5,
    incorrect: 0.09
  }, {
    date: '2017-01-28',
    correct: 10,
    incorrect: null
  }, {
    date: '2017-02-19',
    correct: null,
    incorrect: 50
  }, {
    date: '2017-02-20',
    correct: 75,
    incorrect: 50
  }, {
    date: '2017-02-28',
    correct: 60,
    incorrect: 0.085
  }, {
    date: '2017-03-01',
    correct: 75,
    incorrect: null
  }, {
    date: '2017-03-02',
    correct: 10,
    incorrect: null
  }
]
let returns = []
emptyArray.forEach(x => {
  let objToReplace = incomingData.find(o => o.date === x.date)
  let objIndex = incomingData.indexOf(objToReplace);
  if (objIndex != -1) {
    returns.push(incomingData[objIndex])
  } else {
    returns.push(x)
  }
})
let dates = []
let corrects = []
let incorrects = []
let nulls = []
let nullVal = 0.025
returns.forEach(x => {
  dates.push(x.date)
  if (x.correct != null && x.incorrect != null) {
    nulls.push(null)
  } else if (x.correct == null && x.incorrect != null) {
    nulls.push(nullVal)
  }
  if (x.incorrect == null) {
    incorrects.push(null)
  } else {
    incorrects.push(x.incorrect)
  }
  if (x.correct == null) {
    corrects.push(null)
  } else {
    corrects.push(x.correct)
  }
})
function returnList(key) {
  return returns.map(x => {
    return x[key]
  })
}
function returnNulls() {
  let list = []
  returns.forEach(x => {
    if ((x.correct != null && x.incorrect == null) || (x.correct == null && x.incorrect != null)) {
      list.push(nullVal)
    } else {
      list.push(null)
    }
  })
  return list
}
console.log(returnNulls())
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: returnList('date'),
      datasets: [{
          label: 'none',
          data: returnNulls(),
          spanGaps: false,
          pointStyle: yourImage,
        },
        {
          label: 'Corrects',
          data: returnList('correct'),
          borderWidth: 1,
          pointRadius: 5,
          spanGaps: false,
          fill: false,
          borderColor: 'green',
          pointStyle: 'circle'
        },
        {
          label: 'Incorrects',
          data: returnList('incorrect'),
          fill: false,
          spanGaps: false,
          borderColor: 'red',
          pointStyle: 'triangle',
          pointRadius: 5,
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      events: ['mousemove', 'mouseout', 'click', 'touchstart', 'touchmove'],
      interaction: {
        mode: 'nearest'
      },
      plugins: {
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          callbacks: {
            label: function(item) {},
            title: function(item) {
              let date = item[0].label.split(',').slice(0, 2).join(',')
              let dataSet = item[0].dataset.label
              if (dataSet == 'none') {
                return
              }
              return date + '\n' + dataSet
            }
          }
        },
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          labels: {
            filter: (x, y) => {
              if (!x.text.includes('none')) {
                return x
              }
            },
            usePointStyle: 'true',
            fontColor: 'black',
            fontSize: 12
          }
        },
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Your daily average results for chapter __',
          fontColor: 'black',
          fontSize: 18,
        }
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          ticks: {
            font: {
              size: 12
            }
          },
          min: getStart(),
          max: '2017-03-31',
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'day',
            stepSize: 7
          }
        },
        y: {
          type: 'logarithmic',
          max: 100,
          min: 0.01,
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            callback: function(value,
              index,
              values) {
              switch (value) {
                case 1:
                  return '1 per minute';
                case 0.1:
                  return '.1/min';
                case 0.01:
                  return '.01/min';
                case 0.001:
                  return '.001/min';
                case 10:
                  return '10 per min';
                case 100:
                  return '100 per min';
                case 1000:
                  return '1000 per min';
              }
            },
          }
        },
      },
    },
  }
);
```

the HTML

```
<div id='chart' class='chart' width='400px' height='100%'>
  <canvas id="myChart" class='chart' ></canvas>
</div>
```

and the scripts I'm calling out to

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.3.2/dist/chart.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.27.0/luxon.min.js
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-luxon@0.2.1
```